# $_SESSION for subdomain not being set by a shared php file

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, cdn, subdomain

I have a subdomain set up which includes shared files from another subdomain, so basically a master theme on one subdomain and then child themes on others which all reference the same master subdomain.

In the master subdomain shared files there is a login script that sets a $_SESSION on successful login but it's not saving the session so I checked if the session was being written and got the following error when checking session_save_path is writable:

```
Warning: is_writable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/serverPath/php/session) is not within the allowed path(s): (/serverPath/nameOfDir/:/tmp/) in /serverPath/pathToSharedPHPfile on line ****
```

I thought it was being caused by the fact I'm running the login function via AJAX so that the referrer is the master subdomain url and not the domain I want to log into so I set the cookie params like so:

```
$url =  "https://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}";

$escaped_url = htmlspecialchars( $url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', $escaped_url, true, true);

session_start();

$_SESSION['nameOfSession] = array('key' => 'value', ....);
```

But I'm still getting the same error. Sort of new to all this so my research is hindered by not knowing what to be searching for.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your `error` says it all, the `file` you are trying to reach is out of reach. Next, have you started your session? (`session_start()` at the top of every page you use `sessions` )

Comment: Yea I have: `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', $escaped_url, true, true); session_start();` at the top of every page that needs the session vars. I thought that setting the cookie save path would resolve the issue as the same function works fine on the parent domain, with no issues

Comment: You've answerd this question yourself already, if you set a session from another domain or location than that will not be on another site. Like, you are not able to set a session on your own website and be logged into facebook then.

Comment: So if I move that function into the child theme and not call it via AJAX just a straight forward mysqli_query it should work as expected?

Comment: If you are trying to login on your website but obtaining that `function` through a `ajax` request to another server, then yes. You should just login on your own server, you can still use `ajax`, but you can only set a session for the server you are setting the session on.

Comment: It's not from another server; all the requests are running off the same server. I have a VPS which has my parent domain, a subdomain of that parent that has shared files and other subdomains from the parent domain which are child themes that access the shared files on the shared subdomain. So www.parent.com, shared.parent.com, child.parent.com, child2.parent.com etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129304/discussion-between-nytrix-and-pierre).

Comment: But as you suggest I think it'll be better to move this type of function to it's own file on it's respective domain to avoid confusion.